# How Do I Make Ansible Fail When Matching Wildcards In sdout?

Tags: ansible

I am running SQL using a shell command and the output is:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 10.1.0.4.0 - Production on Thu Sep 6 15:44:35 2007

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
<b>
ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

</b>
```

I am checking for errors in the std using:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: error-codes
      shell: "cat {{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - file1.txt
        - file2.txt
      register: result
      failed_when: "'ERROR' in result.stdout"
```

However, I need to match on multiple lines e.g.

```
ERROR:
ORA-
```

The stdout is a single line so I tried matching using a wildcard but it doesn't appear to match

```
failed_when: "'ERROR.*ORA' in result.stdout"
```

How do I make it fail when using a wildcard?

Comment: Good point. I changed the question to just focus on the wildcard and not the multiline

Comment: See [Testing strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings)

Comment: `failed_when: "'ERROR:' in result.stdout and 'ORA-' in result.stdout"`, If you don't want to play with regex

Comment: you can do `result.stdout| regex_search("(?s)ERROR.*ORA")`

Comment: My above comment is implying that ,stdout is not a single line content. Its a multi line content and its shown wrapped in one line . (?s) makes regex to search the entire record as one line. This is why above command in my command works.

Comment: You have an answer if you add the working comment and the explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result.stdout` is not a single line content. Its a multi line content and its shown wrapped in one line .

Here `(?s)` makes `regex_search` to consider entire record as one line.

```
result.stdout| regex_search("(?s)ERROR.*ORA")
```